# DO function in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to do an insertion which is a little different depending on 3 cases. I've tried to read docs, to transform it into not an anonymous do function, red many post on stackoverflow, but none seemed to hold the answer to my case. My if else statements seem good to me though, most likely a function syntaxe matter.

```
DO $$
BEGIN

IF (SELECT date_start FROM segments_circuits_operation) = '2014-02-14' THEN
INSERT INTO circuits_operation (id_circuit, description, date_start, date_end, speed, length, duration, truck_type, tempest_day)
SELECT seg.id_segment, cir.nomcircuit, seg.date_start, seg.date_end, seg.speed_average, cir.shape_leng, (seg.date_end - seg.date_start), seg.truck_type, "14 février 2014"
FROM segments_circuits_operation seg INNER JOIN circuits_wgs_1984_p cir on seg.id_segment = cir.objectid;

ELSE IF (SELECT date_start FROM segments_circuits_operation) = '2014-03-14' THEN
INSERT INTO circuits_operation (id_circuit, description, date_start, date_end, speed, length, duration, truck_type, tempest_day)
SELECT seg.id_segment, cir.nomcircuit, seg.date_start, seg.date_end, seg.speed_average, cir.shape_leng, (seg.date_end - seg.date_start), seg.truck_type, "14 mars 2014"
FROM segments_circuits_operation seg INNER JOIN circuits_wgs_1984_p cir on seg.id_segment = cir.objectid;

ELSE IF (SELECT date_start FROM segments_circuits_operation) = '2014-03-13' THEN
INSERT INTO circuits_operation (id_circuit, description, date_start, date_end, speed, length, duration, truck_type, tempest_day)
SELECT seg.id_segment, cir.nomcircuit, seg.date_start, seg.date_end, seg.speed_average, cir.shape_leng, (seg.date_end - seg.date_start), seg.truck_type, "13 mars 2014"
FROM segments_circuits_operation seg INNER JOIN circuits_wgs_1984_p cir on seg.id_segment = cir.objectid;

END IF;
END
$$
```

I'm having this syntaxe error.  I'm not fluent at postgreSQL, so an answer might be obvious, but not to me at the moment.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 21: $$
         ^
```

Comment: Dont't do `IF()` SQL has WHERE clases that work great and avoid imperative logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semi-colon after `end`

```
end;
$$
```

If I understand what you mean then the whole thing can be plain sql:

```
insert into circuits_operation (
    id_circuit, description, date_start, date_end,
    speed, length, duration, truck_type, tempest_day
)
select
    seg.id_segment, cir.nomcircuit, seg.date_start, seg.date_end,
    seg.speed_average, cir.shape_leng, (seg.date_end - seg.date_start),
    seg.truck_type,
    to_char(seg.date_start, 'DD month YYYY')
from
    segments_circuits_operation seg
    inner join
    circuits_wgs_1984_p cir on seg.id_segment = cir.objectid;
```

Comment: I never used the case yet, but once I ran your query, all ran perfect except that tempest_day is just empty. Your query seems logical, but for some reason, nothing is inserted in tempest_day. It is a timestamp without time zone data type if it helps to know the why :/

Comment: @Yakobu The updated version is more robust and flexible

Comment: The updated version does make a difference, thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

Use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`. [Documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

Comment: or `elseif`. _The key word ELSIF can also be spelled ELSEIF_